# Setting data for custom control in ASCX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, nullreferenceexception

I need to set data for a custom control in my HTML file but I'm experiencing problems with ParseChildren property which doesn't work and my code raises a "Parser Error" for "Object not set to an instance of an object".

Here is my code behind:

```
namespace UserControls
{
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    public partial class MainVisit : UserControl
    {
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public MyCollection MyList { get; private set; }

        public MainVisit()
        {
            this.MyList = new MyCollection();
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            this.MyList = new MyCollection();
        }
    }


    public class MyCollection : List<SecondaryVisit> { }

    public class SecondaryVisit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SecondaryVisit() { }
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML file

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mscuc" TagName="MainVisitForm" Src="~/UserControls/MainVisit.ascx" %>
<mscuc:MainVisitForm id="MainVisitForm"  runat="server">
    <VisitList>
        <mscuc:SecondaryVisit Name="visit_name" />
    </VisitList>
</mscuc:MainVisitForm>
```

So when I compile and try to execute this code an exception is raised for "Object not set to an instance of an object" at line

Any idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Back in the day, it was not possible to do things like this with a user control - only with custom controls. Now, in the meantime, they have made user controls visible in the Designer, so maybe that has changed. Or maybe not.